# For what functions $f$ is $x^{\sf T}Lf(x) \geq 0$?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, monotone-functions, positive-semidefinite

Let $L = L^{\sf T} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a (weighted) Laplacian matrix of a connected undirected graph. For those not familiar with Laplacians (they are positive semidefinite); for simplicity just take $L = n I_n - 1_{n \times n}$, where $1_{n \times n}$ is the matrix of all ones. I have a vector valued function $f(x) = (f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_n(x_n))$, with whatever regularity you desire. Note the component-by-component decoupling in $f$.

Under what conditions on $f$ does it hold that
$$
x^{\sf T}Lf(x) \geq 0\,,\qquad \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n?
$$

Obviously if $f(x) = x$, it holds. Another simple case I can identify is when the components of $f(x)$ are all the same function: $f_i = f_j = h$, and $h$ is a monotone function. Then the product reduces to

\begin{align*}
x^{\sf T}Lf(x) &= \sum_{i,j=1}^n {(f_i(x_i)-f_i(x_j))(x_i-x_j)}\\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \underbrace{(h(x_i)-h(x_j))(x_i-x_j)}_{\geq 0 \forall x_i, x_j}\\
& \geq 0
\end{align*}

Beyond that, I'm looking for some conditions on $f_1,\ldots,f_n$, possibly accompanied jointly with conditions on $L$.

Comment: btw I think $f_i(x_j)$ should instead be $f_j(x_j)$. Apparently I can't make edits of less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $f_i$ are continuous and $n>1$, your example covers all solutions.

Let $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $E\subseteq I\times I$ be the set of edges (including each edge twice for the two directions). Fix $a\in\mathbb R$ and let $m=\min_{i\in I}f_i(a)$. Let
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  J=\{i\in I\mid f_i(a)=m\},\\
  K=\{i\in I\mid f_i(a)>m\}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Note that $J\neq\emptyset$ and $I=J\sqcup K$. Pick any $b<a$ and define the vector $x$ by $x_i=a$ for $i\in J$, $x_i=b$ for $i\in K$. Then
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  0&\leq&x^TLf(x)\\
    &=&\frac12\sum_{(i,j)\in E}(f_i(x_i)-f_j(x_j))(x_i-x_j)\\
    &=&\sum_{(i,j)\in E\cap(J\times K)}(f_i(a)-f_j(b))(a-b)
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Hence
$$
  0\leq\sum_{(i,j)\in E\cap(J\times K)}(f_i(a)-f_j(b)).
$$
Taking the limit as $b\rightarrow0$,
$$
  0\leq\sum_{(i,j)\in E\cap(J\times K)}(f_i(a)-f_j(a)).
$$
However $f_i(a)-f_j(a)<0$ for any $(i,j)\in J\times K$. Thus $E\cap(J\times K)=\emptyset$. Since the graph was assumed connected, $K=\emptyset$. Thus $f_i(a)=m$ for all $i$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, all the $f_i$ must equal the same function $h$.

Now (assuming $n>1$), break $I$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $J\sqcup K$. Suppose $b<a$. The same calculation as above gives
$$
  0\leq|E\cap(J\times K)|(h(a)-h(b)).
$$
Since the graph is connected, $E\cap(J\times K)\neq\emptyset$, so $h(b)\leq h(a)$. Hence $h$ is nondecreasing.